# CiviMail wysiwyg doesn't respect CiviCRM "Default Drupal Editor" option

Tags: civimail, drupal, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Following instructions on [this page](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Configuring+CiviCRM+to+Use+the+Default+Drupal+Editor), I've set the the CiviCRM wysiwyg to use the `Default Drupal Editor`, using the `Wysiwyg` input format. In my Drupal configuration, the `Wysiwyg` input format is set to use CKEditor.  This seems to work in general, but it doesn't work on the CiviMail "New Mailing" page. Just on that page, the editor does change to the CKEditor version set up in Drupal, but none of the settings I've set for the editor in Drupal (under `Wysiwyg profiles`) seem to apply. All buttons show up in the editor regardless of the ones I select in the settings. This is the case only on the "New Mailing" page. The Wysiwyg shows up correctly on other CiviCRM pages.

Anyone know why this is happening, and whether there's a way to get the wysiwyg profile settings to apply to the editor on this page?

**Note**: I know Civi 4.7 is coming out with updated wysiwyg functionality, but I'm interested in whether I can get this working in the current version, since I'm not sure when I can update.

**Updated to include latest information**

Comment: Are permissions/roles set for using that profile?

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm logging in with user ID 1

Comment: Yeah, permissions seem to be set correctly, and the problem happens for user 1 as well.

Comment: Turns out this is actually only a problem on one page - the CiviMail "New Mailing" page. Updated the question to reflect this.